# Unable to show recent custom post types in default recent posts widget

Tags: custom-post-types, recent-posts

I  have a custom post type "books" and there are already 'books' added. 
However, I am unable to modify `WP_Query` to change Recent Posts widget.
I know that there is filter to modify `WP_Query` args:

```
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'wp130512_recent_posts_args');
function wp130512_recent_posts_args($args) {
    $args['post_type'] = array('post', 'books');
    return $args;
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. I have even tried to modify default-widgets.php (just for test) directly and it doesn't show any 'books' (just 'posts').

I even have tried to add this code (just for test) into default-widgets.php, but it shows nothing. If I add the exact code to my front page (front-page.php), then it shows "books".

```
<?php
$queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=books&posts_per_page=5' );
// The Loop!
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        $queryObject->the_post();
        ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <div><a href="#">View More</a></div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

So, what is the reason I cannot get custom post types inside this widget?

**EDIT**
This is how I register custom pos type.

```
add_action('init', 'init_custom_post_types');
function init_custom_post_types() {
register_post_type('books', array(
        'label' => 'Books',
        'description' => 'Books',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => '',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'books', 'with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','revisions','thumbnail','author','post-formats'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'labels' => array (
          'name' => 'Books',
          'singular_name' => 'Book',
          'menu_name' => 'Books',
          'add_new' => 'Add Book',
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Book',
          'edit' => 'Edit',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Book',
          'new_item' => 'New Book',
          'view' => 'View Book',
          'view_item' => 'View Book',
          'search_items' => 'Search Supporters',
          'not_found' => 'No Supporters Found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Supporters Found in Trash',
          'parent' => 'Parent Book',)) 
    ); 
   ... other custom post types here...
   }
```

Comment: How did you register your custom post type. This is quite unusual. The only thing I can think of is your custom post type and how it is registered

Comment: I have edited my questoin adding register post type example. I am adding it inside functions.php.

Comment: No, everything works perfectly on my side. What version of wordpress are you using. The `widget_posts_args` hook was only added in version 3.4.0. Also, do you have any caching plugins installed. Apart from that, I'm at a loss

Comment: I have 3.9.1 version. Even if there would not be widget_posts_args, I tried to modify default-widget.php directly and it doens't work. Very strange. For quick fix I have created my custom function call inside sidebar.php where I display recent posts using my custom code. And here it works.

Comment: Really strange though. You should post your solution if you ever get this sorted out. Would be very interesting to know what was causing this problem